# Pycharm, Understanding project dependencies, interpreter, and structure

Tags: dependencies, pycharm, structure, interpreter

I'm a beginner of Pycharm user, but I know what the virtual environment does. Meanwhile, I couldn't find any conceptional explanations for understanding the differences among project dependencies, interpreter, and structure.

I just understood the project interpreter. In this pane, we can choose the interpreter (or local environment, mostly, which means the directory of a virtual environment), right?

However, I'm wondering the rest of it.
Dependencies for what and where?
Structure for what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Project Dependencies** allows you to configure the dependencies between projects opened in the same window.
- **Project Structure** allows you to configure content roots for each of the projects opened in the same window.

You can read further,

[Project dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-dependencies.html)

[Project structure](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-structure-dialog.html)

[Projects opened in the same window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/opening-multiple-projects.html)